# How to traverse through this IEnumerator

Tags: c#-4.0

I got an IEnumerator type from a ConcurrentDictionary . I am trying to iterate through it using the following way

```
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>

    Ien  = Concur_Dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in Ien) -->Error here
    {
    }
```

I get the following error

```
Error   4   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' because 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Any suggestions on how I could iterate through this IEnumerator ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually don't want to iterate through the `IEnumerator`; you just iterate over the `IEnumerable` directly:

```
foreach (var pair in Concur_Dictionary) …
```

If, for some reason, you don't have access to the `IEnumerable`, you can do this:

```
while (Ien.MoveNext())
{
    var pair = Ien.Current;
    …
}
```

Comment: Well in this case it is important. Since its thread safe. So I need to iterate over the IEnumerator

Comment: @MistyD: The `foreach` statement calls `GetEnumerator()` behind the scenes.

Comment: @MistyD: NP. Btw, You should make use of `var`. The statement `var Ien = …;` would be much easier to read than what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MoveNext()` of it.

```
var enumerator = getInt().GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    //Line of codes..
}
```

You can do something like this.

Or this can be done.

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    // do your stuff   
}
```

Try this thing it worked for me.